# How to hide single point bar in serie

Tags: highcharts

I need to hide the last point in a serie but have to keep the label. Seems is only possible to set a `pointWidth` but not a `pointHeight`. How can i force to display the label and hide the column bar for the last point?

```
series: [
  {
   type: 'column',
   data: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, { pointWidth: 0, y: 5 }]
  }
]
```

[Here's a demo of the current/expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0O0M.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the color of the last column to transparent:

```
series: [{
  data: [3,5,7,4,{y:5,color: 'transparent'}]
}]
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7o2hafuy/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle i was able to do some changes and get the expected result. Here are my changes http://jsfiddle.net/7o2hafuy/2/. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `dataLabels` [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels) that's possible

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  dataLabels:{
    enabled:true
  },
  data: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, {
    pointWidth: 0,
    y: 5
  }]
}]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/c6o83nm2/)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but seems the `dataLabels` is not doing the trick. I attached an image that explains a bit better what i would like to achieve